# How to create an editable matrix in Shiny app?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny

In this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

if (interactive()) {
    # UI
    ui <- fluidPage(
        selectInput('NumGrig',label = 'Matrix size', choices = c(2:10),selected = 5),
        actionButton("add", "Add Martix"),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.add > 0",
                         uiOutput("grid"))
    )

    # Server
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

        # adding Matrix
        observe({
            if (!is.null(input$add)) {
                m = reactive({matrix('',ncol = input$NumGrig ,nrow = input$NumGrig)})
                output$grid <- renderUI({
                    div(
                        matrixInput(inputId = "newGrid", value = m()),
                        actionButton("start", "Convert") 
                    )
                })
            }
        })
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

I want to create an editable matrix with prespecified dimension, but I get Error that says:

```
Error in matrix: non-numeric matrix extent
```

Why `matrixInput` is not receiving the `input$NumGrig` value that was selected in `selectInput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectInput` returns characters : you just have to convert is to numeric with `as.numeric`.
This works :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

if (interactive()) {
  # UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('NumGrig',label = 'Matrix size', choices = c(2:10),selected = 5),
    actionButton("add", "Add Matrix"),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.add > 0",
                     uiOutput("grid"))
  )
  
  # Server
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # adding Matrix
    observe({
      if (!is.null(input$add)) {
        m = reactive({matrix('',ncol = as.numeric(input$NumGrig) ,nrow = as.numeric(input$NumGrig))})
        output$grid <- renderUI({
          div(
            matrixInput(inputId = "newGrid", value = m()),
            actionButton("start", "Convert") 
          )
        })
      }
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried as.numeric before, but probably in the wrong place. Thank you!